# What is the difference between spiral, flame, aggregation data

Tags: dataset, clustering, data-analysis

What is the difference between spiral, flame, aggregation data? What are the names of the columns, or what are the columns indicate?
For example, spiral is like to:

```
31.95   7.95    3
31.15   7.3     3
30.45   6.65    3
29.7    6       3
28.9    5.55    3
28.05   5       3
27.2    4.55    3
26.35   4.15    3
25.4    3.85    3
24.6    3.6     3
23.6    3.3     3
22.75   3.15    3
21.85   3.05    3
20.9    3       3
```

Flame is like to:

```
1.85    27.8    1
1.35    26.65   1
1.4    23.25    2
0.85    23.05   2
0.5    22.35    2
0.65    21.35   2
1.1    22.05    2
1.35    22.65   2
1.95    22.8    2
```

Aggregation is like to:

```
15.55   28.65   2
14.9    27.55   2
14.45   28.35   2
14.15   28.8    2
13.75   28.05   2
13.35   28.45   2
13       2.15   2
13.45   27.5    2
13.6    26.5    2
12.8    27.35   2
```

I searched but couldn't find a source to illustrate the difference or which columns indicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, without knowing the source of the data, we can't tell you much about the columns. But I assume the first two columns correspond to $x$ and $y$. The third is probably some meta-data? Maybe a cluster number?

For an illustration I found this figure coming from this publication. Maybe that helps you imagine the data's shape.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/338167806_A_Fast_Method_for_Estimating_the_Number_of_Clusters_Based_on_Score_and_the_Minimum_Distance_of_the_Center_Point

[image]

Comment: thanks for replying .. so treating with each type of them will be different ?

Comment: These don't seem to be different kinds of "treatment" in any sense, but rather descriptions of the underlying data shape that results in these shapes. Having a biology background, b) could for example be clusters of cells that behave similarly along the two axis or c) somewhat of a volcano plot.